# My upload bandwidth has disappeared

Tags: networking, server, apache2, 18.04, ftp

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 server at home I use for storing media and family backups.

My ISP line is 20Mbps upload, and speedtests run at home show I get that consistently. I used to be able to max that out with ftp and http transfers.

However, in the last few weeks, I can't do better than 6-7Mbps from apache2 or pure-ftp, despite the speed test still getting the full rate. So something is limiting my transfer speeds, but I can't figure out what.

I've tried turning off the firewall, turning off different network services (e.g. ipsec), but nothing makes a difference. I've tried multiple clients in different cities (doing download speedtests on them first to make sure they're >20M). I've checked the router, and it's not maxing out cpus. The server itself also has very low load.

Any ideas what I could be missing? Or how I could diagnose further?

Comment: Sounds like ISP-induced speed caps. Most speed testing software is *not* actually a 'good example' of the speeds. If you have ruled everything out and bypassed your router in your test and still get the low speed, I'd start looking at your ISP.  Also note that most *residential grade connections* are 'shared', not 'guaranteed', bandwidth; even with my 1Gbps download, 350 Mbps upload plan here when everyone else is using the connection it's down to 200 or less Mbps (sometimes even lower)

Comment: I would definitely call, email or on-line chat with my ISP to check the connection remotely first. Then if they say the hardware is all good I would start searching the software side.